# How is this series rearranged?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I'm stuck at this. How is RHS rearranged? Is it a change of index?

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{n}
- \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}
= \sum_{n=N+1}^{2N} \frac{1}{n}
$$

I'm stuck here:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+ \frac{1}{2N}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} =\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+ \frac{1}{N}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{2N}-(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+ \frac{1}{N})=
\frac{1}{2N}-\frac{1}{N}=\frac{-1}{2N}
$$
Thanks!

Comment: Your subtraction has to be wrong. You take $N$ terms away from $2N$ terms. How come you are only left with two?

Comment: Your very last equation is nonsense - you're leaving out the terms that are hidden by the $\dots$. $(1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5+1/6)-(1+1/2+1/3)=(1/4+1/5+1/6)$.

Comment: You made a trivial mistake. "Dots" don't represent the same number of terms in the two places!

Comment: Remember that $\frac{1}{2N}$ is *not* the next term, it is $N$ terms later than $\frac{1}{N}$.  The term after $\frac{1}{N}$ is $\frac{1}{N+1}$.

Comment: So this is the right expansion? $
\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{N-1}+\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N+1}+\frac{1}{N+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2N}
$. And $ \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{N-1}+\frac{1}{N}$ is canceled out by $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @JDoeDoe Yes.${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also simply derive it from the sigma-notation. You have that
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2N}\frac1n = \sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac1n + \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac1n, $$
and hence 
$$\require{cancel}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2N}\frac1n - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac1n = \left(\cancel{\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac1n} + \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac1n\right)- \cancel{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac1n} = \sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac1n. $$

Answer (score 3):

Your reorder is wrong. See here:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{n}
- \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}=
\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{2N}-\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+ \frac{1}{N}\right)=
$$
$$=
\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N}\right)+\frac{1}{N+1}+\frac{1}{N+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2N}=
\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N}\frac{1}{n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is what it should be like:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{n}- \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}$$
$$= \left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+ \frac{1}{2N}\right) -\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+ \frac{1}{N}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{N+1}+\frac{1}{N+2}+\frac{1}{N+3}+\dots+ \frac{1}{2N}$$
$$=\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N} \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. However, is it even possible to rewrite it with change of index in LHS?